# Is it possible to run a bash command in irc?

Tags: bash, tcl

In ssh i can execute my bash script using

```
./myscript.sh -g House -y 2019 -u https://someurl.com Artist - Album
```

The script reads from a directory which contains sub folders of various artists but when i execute the trigger from IRC it tells me there's an invalid folder name

The irc trigger is `!myscript -g House -y 2019 -u https://someurl.com Artist - Album`.

As it stands I use this code to trigger the IRC command

```
proc dupe:myscript {nick host hand chan arg} {
    set _bin "/home/eggdrop/logfw/myscript.sh"

    if {[catch {exec $_bin "$arg" &} error]} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :Error.. $error"
    } else {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :Running.. $arg"
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is it can't find the folder name as it reporting it as -g House -y 2019 -u https://someurl.com Artist - Album

so i need irc or bash to remove the optarg parts to show just the folder name in irc please.

I think the error comes because tcl is sending a quoted string but not sure how to fix the issue

Comment: Arguably, if `myscript.sh` works with the "argument" `Artist - Album`, something in your script is broken. You aren't passing a single argument there; the shell breaks that into three arguments `Artist`, `-`, and `Album`, which your script appears to be reassembling internally. I would expect `./myscript.sh -g House -y 2019 -u https://someurl.com "Artist - Album"` to be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending `$arg` as one string rather than multiple arguments. The fix is probably to do this:

```
if {[catch {exec $_bin {*}$arg &} error]} {
```

(The rest of your code will be the same.)

---

You probably need to take a few extra steps to defend against assholes doing redirections and other shenanigans. That's easy enough:

```
proc dupe:myscript {nick host hand chan arg} {
    set _bin "/home/eggdrop/logfw/myscript.sh"

    # You might need this too; it ensures that we have a proper Tcl list going forward:
    set arglist [split $arg]

    # Check (aggressively!) for anything that might make exec do something weird
    if {[lsearch -glob $arglist {*[<|>]*}] >= 0} {
        # Found a potential naughty character! Tell the user to get lost…
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :Error.. bad character in '$arg'"
        return
    }

    if {[catch {exec $_bin {*}$arglist &} error]} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :Error.. $error"
    } else {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :Running.. $arg"
    }
}
```